# Problems with sys_extract_utc and summer/wintertime

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone, timezone-offset

I have a problem converting a timestamp to UTC.

Our System Timezone is 'Europe/Berlin'. The actual ZoneOffset at the moment (as it is not summertime yet) is +1. This ZoneOffset will change on March 26 2017 from +1 to +2. (wintertime to summertime).

If I use the function `sys_extract_utc('2017.03.27 00:00')` then the offset which now applies is being used for the calculation. So the result is '2017.03.26 23:00', but I expected the result '2017.03.26 22:00'.

How can I get the correct result?

Comment: correction: of course is use the function  'sys_extract_utc' not 'sys_extract_uts'

Comment: It would help to show a valid command; please edit the question to show what you are really doing so we can replicate it. What is your session time zone? If I set that to Europe/Berlin then `select sys_extract_utc(timestamp '2017-03-27 00:00:00') from dual` does give `26-MAR-17 22.00.00`. Maybe you're really passing a timestamp with time zone value that has +01:00 instead of Europe/Berlin?

Comment: I try this query select sys_extract_utc(timestamp '2017-03-27 00:00:00') from dual and i get 26.03.17 23:00:00,000000000

Comment: OK, once again, what is your *session* time zone? What does `select sessiontimezone from dual` tell you? Is that show +01:00 instead of the region?

Comment: Yes, i get +01:00 for my sessiontimezone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said

> the offset which now applies is being used for the calculation

That isn't quite true. Your session time zone seems to be set to a `+01:00` offset instead of a region name:

```
alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
alter session set TIME_ZONE = '+01:00';
select sys_extract_utc(timestamp '2017-03-27 00:00:00') from dual;

SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(TIM
-------------------
2017-03-26 23:00:00
```

The timestamp literal being supplied has no time zone information, so it's implicitly converted to the session time zone as part of the function call. An offset has no knowledge of summer/wintertime, so no adjustment is (or can be) made. You'd see the same thing if you ran that query after the 27th.

If you set the session time zone to the region instead then you'll get the correct result.

```
alter session set TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin';
select sys_extract_utc(timestamp '2017-03-27 00:00:00') from dual;

SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(TIM
-------------------
2017-03-26 22:00:00
```

You may be able to do that automatically by modifying your operating system environment variables; if not then you can set it in your client or (for SQL*Plus) in a `.login` or `.glogin` setup file.

If you're starting from a value which actually has a region, i.e. is a timestamp with time zone data type, then the session time zone doesn't matter:

```
alter session set TIME_ZONE = '+01:00';
select sys_extract_utc(timestamp '2017-03-27 00:00:00 Europe/Berlin') from dual;

SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(TIM
-------------------
2017-03-26 22:00:00
```

Comment: Many Thanks for the detailed answer! This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: You can set your default session timezone also by environment variable `ORA_SDTZ` or (for Windows only) in Registry at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\ORA_SDTZ`, resp, `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\ORA_SDTZ`